# DDDでStreamの表現の仕方について

Tags: swift, ドメイン駆動設計

FRPを使ったアプリを作っていて思ったのですが、StreamはDDDでどう表現すれば良いのでしょうか？
「GitHubから通知を受け取ってMacの通知を送る」ということをやりたいのですが

```
// stream
let stream = GitHubStream()
stream
    .generateNotificationsStreamAtInterval(10 as NSTimeInterval, since: NSDate())
    .filter { ($0 as Notification).reason == .Mention }
    .filter { ($0 as Notification).subject.isComment() }
    .flattenMap { (notification) in
        let notification = notification as Notification
        return stream.generateCommentStream(
            notification.repository.owner.login,
            repoName: notification.repository.name,
            commentId: notification.subject.commentId!
        )
    }.map { (comment) in
        let comment = comment as Comment
        return UserNotification(
            title: "Hoy",
            subtitle: nil,
            informativeText: comment.body,
            contentImage: NSImage(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: comment.user.avatarUrl)!),
            identifier: nil,
            openUrl: comment.htmlUrl
        )
    }
    .subscribeNext { (userNotification) in
        let userNotification = userNotification as UserNotification
        userNotification.notify()
    }
```

ドメイン層なしにこんな感じのコードになっています。
GitHubStreamとUserNotificationはインフラ層になると思うのですが、インフラ層からリアルタイムに流れてくるデータをどのようにドメイン層で扱えば良いのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift については詳しくありませんが、ドメイン層はインタフェースを規定する場所なので、 GitHubStream や UserNotification のインタフェースを提供する Protocol をドメイン層で提供するのが良いのではないでしょうか。そうすれば、アプリケーション層から利用される Protocol が明確になりますし、インフラ層の GitHubStream では Protocol 要件を満たすことに専念してコードを書くことが出来ます。また、GitHubStream 互換のテスト用のモックを提供したり、GitHubStream の代わりに BitbucketStream を書いたり、将来 GitHub の API 仕様が変わった場合に Protocol を見ながらインフラ層を書きなおしたりすることができます。

なお、質問文に書かれているコード自体も、インタフェースを明確にしつつ（例えば、 activateNotification, inactivateNotification など）ドメインサービスで定義し、実装をインフラ層で持つのが良いと思います。アプリケーション層でそのサービスに対して stream を DI して利用するイメージです。そうすれば、アプリケーション層において、要件に応じて「通知サービス」の実装を切り替えて利用することもできます。

Comment: 前提条件を書き忘れましたが、上記の回答はヘキサゴナルアーキテクチャを用いた場合の設計となります。

Comment: Protocolと言うのはSwiftで言うProtocol/Delegateの話でしょうか？それともヘキサゴナルアーキテクチャでProtocolと呼ばれる何かがあるのでしょうか？

Comment: Swift での Protocol のつもりで書きました（ヘキサゴナルアーキテクチャの言葉ではないです）。Swift は詳しくないのですが、Java の場合は Interface をドメイン層で定義します。ちょうどこれから出版される「実践ドメイン駆動設計」にこのような例が豊富に掲載されています。
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/479813161X

Comment: なるほど。ヘキサゴナルアーキテクチャを適用した場合、

1. ドメイン層からポート層経由でアダプタ層にStreamの読み込みを開始
2. アダプタ層でStreamから読み取った値をポート層経由でドメイン層に渡す
3. ドメイン層に渡された値をポート層経由でアダプタ層に渡しMac通知を流す

という流れのイメージで良いのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そのようなイメージです。利用するアダプタを切り替えれば、例えば Mac の代わりに Console へ通知するようなこともできます。ポートとは「Database ポート」「Notification ポート」のように、外部と接続するための窓口の種類のようなもので、アダプタは「MySQL用のDAO」「Mac 用の Nortification アダプタ」のように、特定のポートのもとで外部接続する具体的な実装になります。